# manual option is not showing in Xcode 11 assistant editor and how to add IBOutlet?

Tags: xcode

[image: like in this image there is not a option of choosing "manual"]

I recently updated to Xcode 11 and some of its user interface changed. in older version of Xcode there was options of accessing files in assistant editor using automatic or **manual**. but in this version of Xcode I can't see any manual option in assistant editor. so I am not able to add *IBOutlet and IBAction* methods to particular storyboard.

so can anyone tell me how to add these actions and outlets, that would be great help. thanks

Comment: Although not a direct answer, here is what I consider a _vastly_ better way to open side-editors from wherever: `⌘⇧O` (cmd-shift-o) then (autocomplete) search your class/method/any symbol and then `Option + Enter` to open/replace it on a side editor.

Comment: This question is not duplicate of marked one, it has a different problem

Comment: I get the same issue on Xcode 12, it is weird. It seems assistant editor is no-sense now as we could press "Add Editor on right" button to open a new editor and navigate to needed file, then do control drag things in that file. Or Alladinian's approach do the job too.

Answer (score 19):

[image]

By pressing the above button, Xcode will split the view and allow you to select a custom file using the file tree at the top.

Comment: This button will open a new editor window along side the current window, but this new window is NOT an assistant editor window as the OP requested. Cannot use this window to create IBOutlet etc.

Answer (score 17):

You are correct.

The Manual option is no longer visible. You can still achieve the same result by doing a quick open using Cmd+Shift+O then type the name of any file you want to open. Press the Alt key and the file will open in the Assistant Editor Window.

As others have noted the new add editor button allows you to add new editors and open files into them. You could file a bug report but you may want to consider that you're likely to get a "works as designed" type of reply.

You can always change or add new keyboard shortcuts to get the behavior you want by viewing the preferences key bindings area and search for the command you want to shortcut.

### Note

> You can still ctrl+drag from storyboard to the class by the Adjust
>   Editor button in the upper right of the storyboard. Then just select
>   Assistant Editor on the list. After which you can make IBOutlets/IBActions.

Answer (score 12):

open your storyboard, hold option key and select the file you want

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation outline of storyboard, try to choose the "correct" item, which you want to set up outlet connections. Say you want to set up an outlet connection for cell of table/collection view.

View Controller > Collection View > Cell > Content View > Image View.

Try to select Cell, "Content View" or "Image View", then check the jump bar of assistant editor, you're probably able to switch to the .swift file you want.

[Reference](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/100-days-of-swift/assistant-editor-doesn-t-show-me-any-class-except-my-viewcontroller/6583)